# Setting user-defined variable with select in stored procedure mariaDB

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm trying to set a user-defined variable to a select statement. I thought this should be a rather easy task, but I continue to get the same error as soon as I try to add a variable. I'm very new at this so please pardon my banter and poor coding knowledge.

When I try to use the "GUI" this is the results I get.

**Input:**
[image: GUI Input]

**Output:**
[image: GUI Output]

When I try using an SQL Query, I get similar results.

**Input:**
[image: Query Input]

**Output:**
[image: Query Output]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try saving it without `DEFINER=root@localhost`

Comment: @Psi I tried but the results seemed to remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further research and found this to work.

**GUI Input:**
[image]

**SQL Query Input:**
[image]

Comment: Yes, you need `BEGIN` and `END`.  Yes, you need to terminate statements with `;`.  That GUI is a rather thin wrapper around MySQL; you really need to understand MySQL to use the GUI.